# How can I prevent users from reverting to an old version of a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to allow users to edit a Google Spreadsheet, but not be able to revert them to prior versions. Is this at all possible?

**USE CASE**
The spreadsheet we use keeps track of snacks consumed, so anytime anyone goes into the break room and grabs some snacks, they go in and update the spreadsheet.
Each user has their own tab and there is also another tab that keeps track of items for sale and their price, and another tab that totals.
So the spreadsheet is constantly getting updated several times a day.
However, if at any point in time someone goes and reverts to a previous version and I don't catch it, extremely quickly everyone else starts then updating an old spreadsheet and it all gets out of whack.

Comment: Yes perhaps you are right, each their own sheet would be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Google Form, which people can use to record their purchases. Just let people access the form and not the sheet.

The form will submit the results to a Google Spreadsheet. Keep the data in this sheet and put any calculations etc. into a different sheet that reads from the first one.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the best solution until google provides some enhancements.

Comment: I'm not even sure that enhancements like that would be a good idea.   fundamentally this is a spreadsheet (free-format calculations canvas), trying to do the job of a multi-user application with a database backend (structured calculation processor).    The mismatch between the basics is too great for a spreadsheet to realistically provide a good solution, IMHO.

Comment: Well if you can lockdown portions of a spreadsheet so that users cannot edit, why not also have an option to only let owners do rollbacks?  Seems a legitimate enhancement if you ask me.

Comment: Also I assume you mean fundamentally as in (In the beginning), but these days people do all kinds of crazy things with spreadsheets.  They are quite application-like.  And if google touts their multi-user editing, then they also ought to add enhancments like this.

Comment: I built applications with spreadsheets back in the mid 1990s.  These days, I know better    :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, all editors of a shared Google Spreadsheet can revert to an old version.

I am not allowed to comment, and this is not the answer you look for, but here goes anyway:

You should decide if you trust the users or not. It seems to me you initially trusted the users to keep there own tab, not so much anymore?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the info.  I'm not allowed to upvote.